# Hide a section in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a menu bar on layout page and put it in a section on layout.

```
@section MenuSection{
<ul class="menubar">
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
}
```

I have multiple view in application associated with layout page. On some views It won't be requiring this menu bar. So I tried hiding section for that view

**Index View-**

```
@{
@RenderSection("MenuSection",required:false)
}
```

But this menu section disappears from layout.

What is the proper way of doing this? Is section is precise way? What would be a definition of section in layout page?

Comment: pass information to your layout page.  controller/action etc.  then put this render in an if statement

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (SomeCondition){
    @RenderSection("MenuSection", required: false)
}
```

The `required` just means that child pages don't *have* to specify that `@section`. But if you want it to display during specific circumstances, place it in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked and we get the controller and action like this

```
var action = (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] ?? "").ToString().ToLower();
var controller = (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] ?? "").ToString().ToLower();
```

the put the render in an if based on this like Brad's answer